# Jquery Assets precompilation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, asset-pipeline, precompile

I am using 'Jquery-rails' gem. when the server compiles all assets, every single plugin from jquery library is attatched to the page in front-end. Is it possible to use only the specific plugins.

These are the files being automatically attached in front-end:-->

jquery.ui.bind,jquery.ui.bounce, jquery.ui.droppable, jquery.ui.explode, jquery.ui.shake,
jquery.ui.slider, jquery.ui.sortable, jquery.ui.spinner,..................
[more than 100 of them]

but i am using only few of them.
how to solve this problem.

Comment: are u using  jquery-ui-rails gem also..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add the specific jquery plugins as required. Download it from here [Jquery plugin Download](https://jqueryui.com/download/). Select the required plugins as per your requirement. Now include the files in your assets folder and change the `layouts/application.html.erb` to make the files available.

Comment: can we configure jqery-ui-rails gem for the same, n if yes, then how to do so?

Comment: no you can't do that with a gem as it's preconfigured for the js files to be includes. Better option is remove this gem file and include the downloaded jquery ui files in layout file or in the files as per requirement